# How to parse the data from json's key by objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a json file like this:

```
{
"Jack": {
    "responseHeader": {
        "returnCode": "200",
        "returnMsg": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responseBody": {
        "email": "Jack@gmailM.com",
        "mobile": "+100000000"
    }
},
"Jimmy": {
    "responseHeader": {
        "returnCode": "200",
        "returnMsg": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responseBody": {
        "email": "Jimmy@gmailM.com",
        "mobile": "+100000001"
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to get the dictionary key "Jack" and "Jimmy" and set them to navigation title.
And I also have a button to switch the navigation title is "Jack" or "Jimmy".
So, Have any idea to do this features.

```
@property NSDictionary* dataDictionary;

- (void)readDataFromFile {

NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myjson" ofType:@"json"];

NSError * error;
NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(error) {

    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}

self.dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                       options:0 error:NULL];

self.title = @"Jack or Jimmy";

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what trouble you are having. You have the top level dictionary in `self.dataDictionary`. Use the `allKeys` method to get the two keys as an array.

Comment: `self.title = [[self.dataDictionary allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@" or "];`

Comment: Have you considered using JSONModel? It allows you to just define the deserialized class' structure, and initialize an object with `[MyClass initWithDictionary:self.dataDictionary]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSArray instance method componentsJoinedByString:

```
NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myjson" ofType:@"json"];

NSError * error;
NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(error) {

    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}

dic = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                       options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray * yourKeys;
yourKeys = [dic allKeys];
strTitle = [yourKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" or "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple you just have to extract all the keys in a array and use them according to you need like this :-

Let's take your data for example:-

```
{
"Jack": {
    "responseHeader": {
        "returnCode": "200",
        "returnMsg": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responseBody": {
        "email": "Jack@gmailM.com",
        "mobile": "+100000000"
    }
},
"Jimmy": {
    "responseHeader": {
        "returnCode": "200",
        "returnMsg": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responseBody": {
        "email": "Jimmy@gmailM.com",
        "mobile": "+100000001"
    }
  }
}
```

By using allKeys method on your dictionary you can get all the keys present in your data i also updated your code to prevent crashes :-

```
-(void)readDataFromFile {
    NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myjson" ofType:@"json"];
    NSError * error;
    NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }else if (fileContents){
        self.dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                               JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                               options:0 error:NULL];
        if (self.dataDictionary){
            NSArray *allKeys = [self.dataDictionary allKeys];
            //allKeys will contain String value and after that you can do anything with your array
            if (allKeys.count){
                self.title = [allKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" or "];
            }
            /*
             You also seprate with comma's or anything you want like this
             if (allKeys.count){
             self.title = [yourKeys componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
             }
             */
        }
    }
}
```